# Recommend Learning about creating your own operating system?

Tags: c#, operating-system

I am interested in learning how I could make my own operating system.

I'm aware that this isn't something that happens overnight.

I have a few questions:

- What kind of knowledge and what concepts would I want to be familiar with to do this?
- Is there any recommended reading on this topic?
- My favorite language is C#, is it possible to code an operating system in this language?

Comment: I recommend to start from the question: what is the reason to create new os?

Comment: My reason is to learn.

Comment: Linux or BSD would be a good, start, with loads of things ready to plug in. Another option would be sometjhing like PIC micro-controller. Note you need to be really up on hardware. So another option to make a start would be writing a driver and adding it to an existing OS. Oh and Happy learning, even if you achieve nothing, you'll learn a lot.

Comment: Where can i get Linux source code?

Comment: @TheCompBoy You can checkout linux sources at [github](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) or at [kernel.org](http://git.kernel.org/)

Comment: @TheCompBoy I've updated my post (added useful resources)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend Andrew S. Tanenbaum, [Operating Systems: Design and Implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_Systems:_Design_and_Implementation)

Good start is to help to improve completed OS (like a [Cosmos](https://www.gocosmos.org/) if you like C#).

**UPD**

Some useful resources:

- Linux sources, https://github.com/torvalds/linux
- OSDev Wiki, http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page
- NachOS Simple and easy to learn OS, http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/tom/nachos/

Comment: + newsgroups: [alt.os.development](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.os.development/topics?gvc=2) and [comp.lang.asm.x86](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.asm.x86/topics?gvc=2)

Answer (score 3):

First go through the basics of OS ...Read Galvin( the best book for it) then decide how you want to approach the development. My colleagues are working on OS development in UBUNTU.

Answer (score 2):

Depends how awesome you are. Probably the best place to start is by doing your own linux distro and building on that. c# is not the best language to build an OS. There is an implementation on code project, however, the best place to start is assembly and then build on that. Windows is c/c++ as i think most operating systems are on top of the assembly parts.

Comment: Linux is also made in C/C++ yes ?

Comment: Think so, may depend on distro

Comment: @TheCompBoy Formally, Linux is not an operating system. It's a kernel of OS. Look at the graph of programming languages https://github.com/torvalds/linux/graphs/languages

Comment: Where can i get the source of Linux?

Comment: https://github.com/mirrors/linux-2.6

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to code the OS in C#?,

http://www.silveos.com/
A silverlight OS, it runs nice on WP7

If you want a native OS, it's "impossible" to make entirely out of C#, because C# runs over a virtual machine, and the VM runs over the OS XD.

The best way to make an OS is targeting low range embedded systems, because you don't have to worry about virtual memory and other complicated stuff. If you want to go that way check out https://github.com/DVDPT/Micro-Operating-System, my own OS made for ARM and AVR embedded systems.

Finally read Operating system concepts and study tiny OS like TNKernel, FreeRTOS, eCos. And then jump to the main OS like linux or windows.

Answer (score 1):

Cosmos, which stands for C++/C# Open Source Managed Operating System allows you to build and compile your own operating system for personal use.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CosmosMS5.aspx

http://www.GoCosmos.org

http://Cosomos.CodePlex.com

It allows you to build a command-line which can be booted with a Virtual Machine. After that, you can start using Gnome or KDE to build a UI for the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Not completely.

You have to write certain parts in assembly, also you'd have the problem of the CLR, but that could be overcome by using the .NET Micro Framework. Also, to some part this has been done by Microsoft in their [Singularity OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28operating_system%29). If you want to get into OS Development I suggest reading some tutorials at the [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) or check the [Bona Fide OS Developer](http://www.osdever.net).